# FetchDistributedMapCache isn't getting the answer I need

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a DistributedMapCache, and 2 processors, one to fetch and one to put. The put works fine, I belived. But when I run the the fetch, the processor give me another value, I mean, not the value related with the key I pass. It gives me the same answer for different keys. In the processor config, I have the same value in the Cache Entry Identifier. Any ideas why I'm getting this answer?

Comment: You'll need to post a template of your flow, or at least screen shots of the config for both cache processors.

Comment: I just found the answer. The key value I was send in the attribute was wrong. I was using subscriberId instead of ${subscriberId}, that was the mistake